# Как получить размер битового поля структуры на этапе компиляции?

Tags: c++, c++20

Есть битовая структура. Есть ли возможность на этапе компиляции узнать размер (в битах) поля этой структуры? Сама структура находится на стороне и менять её код нельзя.

```
// Код, недоступный для изменения.
#pragma pack( push, 1 )
struct Foo {
   uint16_t field_a : 12;
   uint8_t field_b : 6;
   uint8_t field_c: 8;
};
#pragma pack( pop )

// Как получить размер field_b структуры?
size_t size_of_field_b = ???; // Должны получить 6.
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131484/discussion-on-question-by-rivand--------).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переносимого (работающего во всех реализациях компиляторов C++) способа узнать размер битового поля (кол-во бит) не существует. Есть способы, которые, скорее всего, будут работоспособны, но это не гарантируется в общем случае.

Основная концепция, которая может быть использована для вычисления размера битового поля, заключается в том, чтобы найти максимальное значение, которое может быть туда записано, что укажет на возможное кол-во бит, выделенных под это поле. При этом существуют следующие ограничения, которые следует учитывать:

- Если присвоить битовому полю значение, которое явно в него не укладывается, оно, скорее всего, будет просто усечено, но реализация вправе выбрать другое поведение. Пример:

  ```
  uint8_t field_b : 6 = 127;
  ```

  для clang выведет предупреждение об усечении 127 до 63 (максимальное значение, которое можно сохранить в 6 битах):

  ```
  implicit truncation from 'int' to bit-field changes value from 127 to 63 
  [-Wbitfield-constant-conversion]
  ```
- Заданный размер битового поля может превышать разрядность подлежащего типа, например:

  ```
  uint8_t field_b : 16;
  ```

  В этом случае биты, не поместившиеся в подлежащий тип, не будут доступны через битовое поле, и станут выполнять роль заполнителя - пустышки до следующего члена или конца объемлющего класса. Возможное предупреждение:

  ```
  width of bit-field 'field_b' (16 bits) exceeds the width of its type; 
  value will be truncated to 8 bits [-Wbitfield-width]
  ```

  Т.о. записать в поле значение, которое больше 8 бит не получится, несмотря на то, что размер битового поля задан как 16. Следовательно и определить размер путём записи "максимального значения" не получится.

Если считать, что указанные выше ограничения не распространяются на наш случай, то [код может быть таким](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XVBcYY4k8OAN4JT5) (на базе кода из комментария [wololo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/262953/wololo)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <bit>

#pragma pack( push, 1 )
struct Foo {
   std::uint16_t field_a : 12;
   std::uint8_t  field_b : 6;
   std::uint8_t  field_c : 8;
};
#pragma pack( pop )

template <int bit_width>
void test() {
    std::cout << bit_width << '\n';
}

int main() {
   constexpr Foo foo{0, static_cast<std::uint8_t>(-1), 0};
   constexpr int width_b = std::bit_width(foo.field_b);
   test<width_b>();
}
```

Вывод:

```
6
```

Comment: я конечно понимаю, что сейчас 2021 год, но с++20 ещё не везде стандарт де факто. Да, о с++11/14 давно можно не предупреждать, но о 20 наверно все таки стоит в ближайший год-два.

Comment: @KoVadim у ТС номинально была метка [tag:c++20] в вопросе.

Comment: боюсь, что он просто проставил.

Comment: А меток то оказывается две: [c++20](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) и  [с++20](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%2b%2b20).

Comment: @wololo неожиданно. Хотя и предcказуемо. C другими так же было в cвоё время.